# Why don't I get my return value from my form

Tags: string, delphi, parameters

With this code I call a form

```
procedure TfrmMain.actDevTest_2Execute(Sender: TObject);
var
  SelectedApp: string;
begin
  if ApplicationSelect(Self, SelectedApp) then
    ShowMessage(SelectedApp);
end;
```

The form is looking like the following

```
unit F_JsApplicationSelect;

interface

uses
{$Include UniDACCommon.inc}
  Db, MemDS, DbAccess, Uni,
  Classes, Controls, Forms,
  U_Forms.Move,
  Winapi.Messages, U_CustomMessages,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, Buttons, ComCtrls,
  cxGroupBox, cxGraphics, cxControls, cxLookAndFeels,
  cxLookAndFeelPainters, cxStyles, dxSkinsCore, dxSkinOffice2010Blue,
  dxSkinscxPCPainter, cxCustomData, cxFilter, cxData, cxDataStorage, cxEdit,
  cxNavigator, cxDBData, cxCheckBox, cxTextEdit, cxContainer, Vcl.Menus,
  cxButtons, cxGridLevel, cxGridCustomTableView, cxGridTableView,
  cxGridDBTableView, cxClasses, cxGridCustomView, cxGrid,
  dxmdaset;

type
  TfrmJsApplicationSelect = class(TForm)
    grdApplicationsView1: TcxGridDBTableView;
    grdApplicationsLevel1: TcxGridLevel;
    grdApplications: TcxGrid;
    colContact: TcxGridDBColumn;
    colSection: TcxGridDBColumn;
    colSelected: TcxGridDBColumn;
    cxGroupBox1: TcxGroupBox;
    btnOK: TcxButton;
    srcApplications: TUniDataSource;
    mdApplications: TdxMemData;
    mdApplicationsfldselected: TBooleanField;
    mdApplicationsfldcontact: TStringField;
    mdApplicationsfldsection: TStringField;
    mdApplicationsfldposition: TStringField;
    mdApplicationsflddate: TDateField;
    mdApplicationsfldguid: TStringField;
    colPosition: TcxGridDBColumn;
    colDdate: TcxGridDBColumn;
    procedure FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure grdApplicationsView1CellDblClick(Sender: TcxCustomGridTableView;
      ACellViewInfo: TcxGridTableDataCellViewInfo; AButton: TMouseButton;
      AShift: TShiftState; var AHandled: Boolean);
  private
    procedure SetupApplications;
    procedure MessageClose(var aMessage: TMessage); message WM_FORMCLOSE;
  public
    constructor Create(aOwner: TComponent; var aApplication: string); reintroduce;
  end;

  function ApplicationSelect(aOwner: TComponent; var aApplication: string): boolean;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  System.SysUtils, Winapi.Windows,
  F_UniConn,
  U_Logfile,
  U_AppDb, U_User;

var
  lApplication  : string;

function ApplicationSelect(aOwner: TComponent; var aApplication: string): boolean;
begin
  with TfrmJsApplicationSelect.Create(aOwner, aApplication) do
    try
      Result := ShowModal = mrOK;
    finally
      Release;
    end;
end;

procedure TfrmJsApplicationSelect.MessageClose(var aMessage: TMessage);
begin
  Close;
end;

procedure TfrmJsApplicationSelect.SetupApplications;
var
  Query: TUniQuery;
begin
  Query := frmUniConn.CreateQuery;
  try
    Query.SQL.Clear;
    Query.SQL.Add('SELECT fldapplication_guid');
    Query.SQL.Add('      ,fldapplication_date');
    Query.SQL.Add('      ,fldcontact_name');
    Query.SQL.Add('      ,fldsection_desc');
    Query.SQL.Add('      ,fldposition_desc');
    Query.SQL.Add('      ,fldcreated_by');
    Query.SQL.Add('  FROM ' + QueryJsApplications);
    Query.SQL.Add(' WHERE (fldcreated_by = :fldcreated_by)');
    Query.SQL.Add(' ORDER BY fldapplication_date DESC');
    Query.ParamByName('fldcreated_by').AsString                     := User.ID;
    try
      Query.Execute;
      if Query.RecordCount > 0 then
        begin
          while not Query.Eof do
            begin
              mdApplications.Open;
              mdApplications.Append;
              mdApplications.FieldByName('fldselected').AsBoolean := False;
              mdApplications.FieldByName('fldguid').AsString := Query.FieldByName('fldapplication_guid').AsString;
              mdApplications.FieldByName('flddate').AsDateTime := Query.FieldByName('fldapplication_date').AsDateTime;
              mdApplications.FieldByName('fldcontact').AsString := Query.FieldByName('fldcontact_name').AsString;
              mdApplications.FieldByName('fldsection').AsString := Query.FieldByName('fldsection_desc').AsString;
              mdApplications.FieldByName('fldposition').AsString := Query.FieldByName('fldposition_desc').AsString;
              mdApplications.FieldByName('fldguid').AsString := Query.FieldByName('fldapplication_guid').AsString;
              mdApplications.Post;
              Query.Next;
            end;
          mdApplications.First;
        end;
    except
      on E:exception do
        Logfile.Error('F_JsApplicationSelect.SetupApplications: ' + E.Message);
    end;
  finally
    Query.Free;
  end;
end;

constructor TfrmJsApplicationSelect.Create(aOwner: TComponent; var aApplication: string);
begin
  inherited Create(aOwner);
  lApplication  := aApplication;
end;

procedure TfrmJsApplicationSelect.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  try
    mdApplications.First;
    while not mdApplications.Eof do
      begin
        if mdApplications.FieldByName('fldselected').AsBoolean = True then
          begin
ShowMessage(mdApplications.FieldByName('fldguid').AsString);
            lApplication := mdApplications.FieldByName('fldguid').AsString;
ShowMessage(lApplication);
          end;
        mdApplications.Next;
      end;
  except
    on E: exception do
      Logfile.Error('F_JsApplicationSelect.FormClose: ' + E.Message);
  end;
end;

procedure TfrmJsApplicationSelect.FormKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  If Ord(Key) = 27 Then
    ModalResult := mrAbort;
end;

procedure TfrmJsApplicationSelect.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetupApplications;
  ActiveControl := grdApplications;
  if grdApplicationsView1.DataController.RecordCount > 0 then
    begin
      grdApplicationsView1.Controller.GoToFirst(False);
      grdApplicationsView1.Controller.FocusedRecord.MakeVisible;
    end;
end;

procedure TfrmJsApplicationSelect.grdApplicationsView1CellDblClick(
  Sender: TcxCustomGridTableView; ACellViewInfo: TcxGridTableDataCellViewInfo;
  AButton: TMouseButton; AShift: TShiftState; var AHandled: Boolean);
begin
  try
    mdApplications.Edit;
    mdApplications.FieldByName('fldselected').AsBoolean := Not mdApplications.FieldByName('fldselected').AsBoolean;
    mdApplications.UpdateRecord;
  except
    on E: exception do
      Logfile.Error('F_JsApplicationSelect.grdApplicationsView1CellDblClick: ' + E.Message);
  end;
end;


end.
```

But why don't I get any value in my SelectedApp variable?
I have another form with identical functions only the var I send to it is a TStringList - that works OK. But the string doesn't work at all.

Comment: Because you're not returning anything back to your `aApplication` parameter.

Comment: I have another form where the code is


function AttachmentsSelect(aOwner: TComponent; const aCaption, aApplication: string; var aList: TStringList): boolean;
begin
  with TfrmJsAttachmentsSelect.Create(aOwner, aCaption, aApplication, aList) do
    try
      Result := ShowModal = mrOK;
    finally
      Release;
    end;
end;

Called with           AttachmentsSelect(Self, 'Vælg bilag der skal vedhæftes mail', GuidZero, ListAttachments); I have something in ListAttachments after the call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that is needed to understand this is:

```
function ApplicationSelect(aOwner: TComponent; 
  var aApplication: string): boolean;
begin
  with TfrmJsApplicationSelect.Create(aOwner, aApplication) do
    try
      Result := ShowModal = mrOK;
    finally
      Release;
    end;
end;
```

which in turn calls

```
constructor TfrmJsApplicationSelect.Create(aOwner: TComponent; 
  var aApplication: string);
begin
  inherited Create(aOwner);
  lApplication  := aApplication;
end;
```

So, you are asking why the caller of `ApplicationSelect` does not observe any modification to `aApplication` when the call to `ApplicationSelect` returns.

You don't modify the `var` parameter `aApplication` in `ApplicationSelect`. You do pass it as a var parameter to `TfrmJsApplicationSelect.Create` but again `TfrmJsApplicationSelect.Create` does not modify it. Since a `string` variable is a value, the caller sees no modification to the variable, because it was not modified.

My other comment about `ApplicationSelect` is that you should call `Free` rather than `Release`.

Beyond that I could make many more comments about your code, but I will refrain from attempting a comprehensive code review and comment solely on the direct question that you asked.

---

In the comments you ask why changing `aApplication` to `TStringList` allows the caller to observe modifications. That's because Delphi class variables are references to the object. When you pass a `TStringList` variable as a parameter, you are passing a reference to the object. When you call methods on that object, any mutations are performed on the actual object.

---

So, how would I change this code to allow a string value to be returned? First of all I would make `ApplicationSelect` be a function that returns a `string`. In case of cancellation I would `Abort`.

```
function SelectApplication(aOwner: TComponent): string;
var
  Form: TfrmJsApplicationSelect; 
begin
  Form := TfrmJsApplicationSelect.Create(aOwner);
  try
    if Form.ShowModal <> mrOK then
      Abort;
    Result := Form.Application;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;
```

I would absolutely remove the global variable `lApplication`. You should avoid using global variables if at all possible. I'd remove every single one from the code here.

Instead add a private field to the form to hold the information:

```
FApplication: string;
```

And expose it as a public property:

```
property Application: string read FApplication;
```

Then the form merely needs to set `FApplication` and the caller can see that value.

Comment: My main issue is why it doesn't work with a string as param when the form I have that is called with a TStringList works when called in exact the same way

Comment: please share your comments - I am not an expert in Delphi and want to learn

Comment: That's because a string list is a class and so is a reference type. A string has value semantics. Give me a minutes to expand in an edit.

Comment: OK - think I got it now. I will change the function ApplicationSelect to make the cahnges to aApplication befor the call to Free. That should do it I think

Comment: @OZ8HP I've given you a guide now on how to resolve this

Comment: I will give it a go and see the result - TNX